# Does the Size of a Third Party Library (In Terms of Disk Usage) Impact Application Performance?

Tags: php, frameworks, doctrine

If I'm writing a PHP project and decide to use a third-party ORM or DBAL like Doctrine, does the size of that project (in terms of MB of source code) impact application performance?

If I include a PHP library that's 200MB, but only use 2MB worth of classes and resources in it, does the other 198MB impact application performance?

Comment: If you have a library that is 200mb and only using 2mb would indicate there are modules or parts of it not being used. In this case they are only taking up diskspace and no more.

Comment: since you are hopefully using a bytecode cache, the answer is no, it doesnt matter. also, this cannot be reasonably answered without knowing how the class code is included, e.g. lazy loading or all at once. On a sidenote, I am pretty sure there is a question like this already.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

tldr; **just don't worry about it ;-)**

Okay, so here is a *totally generic answer*:

Measure the performance: where is/are the bottlenecks? Is there an issue? Memory? Disk access? Disk quota? Other?

Depending on system resources and library usage/design the "on disk" size *might* make a difference ... but it probably has little effect. (Although from the question, as far as I can gather, 198MB are "useless" as they are not code or resources? Don't make your Working Copy, tests, or additional documentation, etc., "live": these things belong *only* on build/development machines.)

In any case, a good library will be modularized and only load what is needed and the only way to know the impact of the library, if any, "for certain", is to *test* the library usage in the target environment.

Comment: +1.  Measure measure measure.  The only way to really know how much impact a library has on your project is to measure it yourself.  It's worth noting that only code that is `include()`ed in some way will have an impact.  You can drop 200MB of code in your repository but if nothing ever includes it then it will have no application performance impact

Answer (score 0):

In fact it does.

In php there is complilation. The source code is parsed, compiled into
a bytecode (intermediate code), which is then interpreted (whether code used or not). In C++ however, this latency is minimized in uncalled scripts or functions, particularly if code is well optimized.

Even removing dead spaces and condensing lines can have an impact, so the weight of sorting thorugh a php file with two hundred functions (As opposed to ten), does create latency in a code base - even if the majority of functions go uncalled.

You can also find a lot of discussion about this in Joomla forums - as it's known for coming packed with so many functions that the majority are rarely used in a single application

http://docs.joomla.org/

Hope that helps,

Comment: Minify is for JavaScript and CSS code though, not PHP. Minifying frontend libraries is a separate thing from minifying the internal code base of a PHP library. On the PHP end, I don't believe the impact there is nearly as significant

Comment: Yes. Totally agree. I was simply using the minify best practice as an example of how PARSING and LOADING alone can affect efficiency. But, you're right - I should have clarified this. I've since edited my response to keep things more clear. Thanks.